# StackOverflowException is thrown when serialising circular dependent ISerializable object with ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have a legacy application that used binary serialisation to persist the data. Now we wanted to use Json.net 4.5 to serialise the data without much changes to the existing classes.

Things were working nice till we hit a circular dependent class. Is there any workaround to solve this problem?

Sample code as shown below

```
[Serializable]
class Department : ISerializable
{
    public Employee Manager { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Department() { }
    public Department( SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context )
    {
        Manager = ( Employee )info.GetValue( "Manager", typeof( Employee ) );
        Name = ( string )info.GetValue( "Name", typeof( string ) );
    }
    public void GetObjectData( SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context )
    {
        info.AddValue( "Manager", Manager );
        info.AddValue( "Name", Name );
    }
}

[Serializable]
class Employee : ISerializable
{
    [NonSerialized] //This does not work
    [XmlIgnore]//This does not work
    private Department mDepartment;
    public Department Department
    {
        get { return mDepartment; }
        set { mDepartment = value; }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Employee() { }
    public Employee( SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context )
    {
        Department = ( Department )info.GetValue( "Department", typeof( Department ) );
        Name = ( string )info.GetValue( "Name", typeof( string ) );
    }

    public void GetObjectData( SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context )
    {
        info.AddValue( "Department", Department );
        info.AddValue( "Name", Name );
    }
}
```

And the test code

```
Department department = new Department();
department.Name = "Dept1";

Employee emp1 = new Employee { Name = "Emp1", Department = department };
department.Manager = emp1;

Employee emp2 = new Employee() { Name = "Emp2", Department = department };
IList<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
employees.Add( emp1 );
employees.Add( emp2 );

var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize( memoryStream, employees );

memoryStream.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );
IList<Employee> deserialisedEmployees = formatter.Deserialize( memoryStream ) as IList<Employee>; //Works nicely

JsonSerializerSettings jsonSS= new JsonSerializerSettings();
jsonSS.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
jsonSS.TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full;
jsonSS.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
jsonSS.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; //This is not working!!
//jsonSS.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize; //This is also not working!!
jsonSS.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
string jsonAll = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( employees, jsonSS ); //Throws stackoverflow exception
```

**Edit1**: The issue has been reported to Json (http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/23668)

**Edit2**: Serialization works fine in version 4.5 R11 but de-serialization still not working

**Edit3**: Actually Serialization itself is not working when circular reference object is not null

**Edit4**: Comment from the Json.net issue base is that the problem is at your end and closed the issue. But i could not find out what is wrong with my code. I posted another **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797707/json-net-serialisation-deserialisation-not-working-for-iserializable-object-tha)** regarding this. Thank you all for answering, voting...

Comment: Does json.net even *look* at `ISerializable` ?

Comment: Yes sir, it works perfectly fine if there are no circular dependency. All my properties and private variables that are set in the GetObjectData is also serialised properly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'll need both `ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize` and `PreserveReferencesHandling.All` to replicate the behavior of binary serialization.  The resulting JSON may not be nearly as pretty, though.

**EDIT:** I've looked deeper into JSON.Net 4.5r10 and discovered a deficiency: `JsonSerializerInternalWriter` doesn't check `#ShouldWriteReference` for references obtained via `ISerializable`.

With the `foreach` loop in `#SerializeISerializable` rewritten as below, your object graph round-trips successfully.

```
  foreach (SerializationEntry serializationEntry in serializationInfo)
  {
    writer.WritePropertyName(serializationEntry.Name);
    var entryValue = serializationEntry.Value;
    var valueContract = GetContractSafe(entryValue);
    if (ShouldWriteReference(entryValue, null, valueContract, null, member))
    {
      WriteReference(writer, entryValue);
    }
    else
    {
      SerializeValue(writer, entryValue, valueContract, null, null, member);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have tried what you have said, but it still throws the exception.

Comment: It works. That is no exceptions are thrown. However i do not get the manager in the department object. i.e. it is null when deserialised

Comment: JSon serialisation with ISerialisable (GetObjectData, and serialisation constructor) and without produces the same output. So it seems that the problem is with the deserialisation. Any help appreciated.

Comment: @renep I inspected the JSON generated by the writer and it looked correct, so there might be bugs on both read and write implementations. I'm guessing that `ISerializable` handling is really deficient in JSON.Net simply because it's not commonly used, or at least not as a replacement for binary serialization.

Comment: Thank you Jeff. I am accepting your answer and shall try posting this bug to Json

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
[Serializable]
 class Employee : ISerializable
 {
   [NonSerialized]
   [XmlIgnore]
   public Department Department { get; set; }
```

> **NonSerialized** Indicates that a field of a serializable class should
>   not be serialized.
>
> **XmlIgnore** Instructs the Serialize method of the **XmlSerializer** not to
>   serialize the public field or public read/write property value

Comment: I guess '[NonSerialized]' is only applicable to Fields. I have converted the property to have a backing field and applied the attribute but it still not working. Updated the question. But i do not want to ignore the value. I want the value anyway that is why it is in the GetObjectData method