# Deep cloning a deep object in C# (very deep)

Tags: c#, pointers, reflection, clone, antlr4

I am writing a toy language with Antlr4 and C#. Now i am trying to write a class system. But a big problem stopped my all work. When i try to clone instance of a user created class , everything in it references to original class. My 'Class' code is here

```
[Serializable]
public class Class : ICloneable
{
    public string ID;
    public ClassDef ClassContent = new ClassDef();

    public Helper ErrorHandler = new Helper();

    public Class()
    {
        ID = "";
    }
    public Class(string id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }

    public void Create(MainGrammarParser.ClassblockContext block)
    {
        ClassDef def = new ClassDef();
        def.Visit(block);
        ClassContent = def;
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        Class clone = new Class(ID);
        clone.ClassContent = ClassContent.DeepClone();
        return clone;
    }
}
```

and code for 'ClassDef'

```
public class ClassDef : SuperClass, ICloneable
{
    public override bool VisitClassStatFunctionDef([NotNull] MainGrammarParser.ClassStatFunctionDefContext context)
    {
        FunctionDefParser fd = GetFunctionDefParser();
        fd.Visit(context.functiondef());
        return true;
    }

    public override bool VisitClassStatElementDef([NotNull] MainGrammarParser.ClassStatElementDefContext context)
    {
        string id = context.classelem().ID().GetText();
        if (IsVarExists(id) || IsFunctionExists(id) || IsClassExists(id))
        {
            ErrorHandler.DuplicateError("[ELEMENT] '" + id  + "'");
        }
        ExpParser exp = GetExpParser();
        VarObject v = new VarObject(id);
        v.Value = exp.Visit(context.classelem().exp());
        Variables.Add(v);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and a superclass code

```
public class SuperClass : MainGrammarBaseVisitor<bool>, ICloneable
{
    public VarCollection Variables = new VarCollection();
    public FunctionCollection Functions = new FunctionCollection();
    public ClassCollection Classes = new ClassCollection();

    public Helper ErrorHandler = new Helper();

    public VarObject GetVar(string id)
    {
        if (!IsVarExists(id))
        {
            ErrorHandler.NotFoundError("[DEFINITION] '" + id + "'");
        }
        return Variables.Find(id);
    }

    public Function GetFunction(string id)
    {
        if (!IsFunctionExists(id))
        {
            ErrorHandler.NotFoundError("[METHOD] '" + id + "'");
        }
        return Functions.Find(id);
    }

    public Class GetClass(string id)
    {
        if (!IsClassExists(id))
        {
            ErrorHandler.NotFoundError("[CLASS] '" + id + "'");
        }
        return Classes.Find(id);
    }

    public bool IsVarExists(string id)
    {
        if (!Variables.Contains(id)) { return false; }
        return true;
    }

    public bool IsFunctionExists(string id)
    {
        if (!Functions.Contains(id)) { return false; }
        return true;
    }

    public bool IsClassExists(string id)
    {
        if (!Classes.Contains(id)) { return false; }
        return true;
    }

    public ExpParser GetExpParser()
    {
        ExpParser output = new ExpParser();
        output.Parent = this;
        return output;
    }

    public EqualityParser GetEqualityParser()
    {
        EqualityParser output = new EqualityParser();
        output.Parent = this;
        return output;
    }

    public FunctionDefParser GetFunctionDefParser()
    {
        FunctionDefParser output = new FunctionDefParser();
        output.Parent = this;
        return output;
    }

    public IfParser GetIfParser()
    {
        IfParser output = new IfParser();
        output.Parent = this;
        return output;
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        SuperClass output = new SuperClass();
        output.Variables = Variables.DeepClone();
        output.Functions = Functions.DeepClone();
        output.Classes = Classes.DeepClone();
        return output;
    }

    public SuperClass()
    { }
}
```

I writed VarCollection, FunctionCollection and ClassCollection myself
They are just lists with find and exists methods.
When i try a code like this in my language

```
class abc
{
    this a = "a"
    this b = "b"
    this c = "c"
    void abc(){}
}
newabc1 = new abc()
newabc1.a = 10
new1a = newabc1.a
newabc2 = new abc()
new2a = newabc2.a
```

both 'new1a' and new2a is set to 10.
I tried most of techniques including: Reflection, Serialization, JsonSerialization, ICloneable, MemberWiseClone...

In serialization, I need to put [Serializable] to every class, including Antlr4 auto generated classes. So when I update grammar I need to put them again.

In Json Serialization(NewtonJson), serialization enters a infinite loop (Serializator warned me about self referencing loop and i disabled loop error).

Reflection, IClonable, MemberWiseClone, none of these worked correctly. They reference same address at memory so i get same error.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, but not really :) I used dictionary instances as classes (like in JavaScript). Creating serialized objects in NewtonJson is inefficent when you use it with Antlr, because HUGE source codes makes serialization very slow (abt 2-3s). This is my solution to problem. Do anyone know a parser generator or a great tutorial to creating languages, this is my last question before I mark this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use serialize to deep clone objects, but keep in mind that you have to set:

```
ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
```

to your serializer, to prevent the enter in infinite loop. This is if you are working with [Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) but similar [ReferenceLoopHandling setting](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReferenceLoopHandlingIgnore.htm) options exists for many serializers.

Comment: Just tried (again) and entered a infinite loop :( Code:             JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source, settings);
            return (T)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialized, settings);

Comment: @YahyaGedik how did you used it, and what version of Newtonsoft do you use?

Comment: Just downloaded from it's site yesterday. 9.0.1. Most problems come from Antlr4 auto generated files. Because they are extremely complex and self referencing(?).

Comment: @YahyaGedik please see the answer in [this question too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412359/stackoverflowexception-is-thrown-when-serialising-circular-dependent-iserializab).

Comment: Not very helpful... I don't think error is with Newtonsoft Json, and i didn't understand (well) the answer in question...

Comment: @YahyaGedik I tried to help you saying that you can use Json Newtonsoft to clone objects, with the setting I have mentioned, which should work. Also, why do you try to clone the methods of a class, since they are stateless?

Comment: I am not trying to clone methods. Just variables, user-defined classes and user-defined functions. But user-defined functions/classes have a block. This block is from ANTLR4 auto generated parsers. This makes things very hard. I solved problem but this technique is not good. Performance is dropping when we tre to create new instance of a class in language. I think I should use something else to create class system, or to create language.

Comment: @YahyaGedik I understand now, sorry, I guess my answer wasn't so helpful. You can post your own solution as an answer and mark it instead. About the performance, I guess it will be the best thing to open a separate question, and maybe there you will receive more help. In this point, I suggest to make a question shorter than this one, so readers won't be discouraged to read it. Cheers! :)