# Deserialize from minimal JSON to hierachical objects with mandatory back-references

Tags: c#, json.net

Assume those hierachical object structure: `Tree`➻`Branch`➻`Leaf`

```
public class Tree
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Branch> Nodes { get; set; } = new List<Branch>();
}
public class Branch
{
    public Branch(Tree parent) { Parent = parent; }
    public Tree Parent { get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Leaf> Nodes { get; set; } = new List<Leaf>();
}
public class Leaf
{
    public Leaf(Branch parent) { Parent = parent; }
    public Branch Parent { get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

---

A not so simple serialization output would be (using `ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize` AND `PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`):

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "Name": "AnOakTree",
    "Nodes": [
        {
            "$id": "2",
            "Parent": {
                "$ref": "1"
            },
            "Name": "TheLowestBranch",
            "Nodes": [
                {
                    "$id": "3",
                    "Parent": {
                        "$ref": "2"
                    },
                    "Name": "OneOfAMillionLeaf"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Deserialization works perfectly, nothing to complain! But I'd like to omit reference handling at all to **reduce JSON footprint and improve readability**.

What's the best way to deserialize JSON without reference informations and invoke the constructors with the correct parameter (the instance of the parent node)? So that the back-references will be recreated by code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StackOverflowException is thrown when serialising circular dependent ISerializable object with ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412359/stackoverflowexception-is-thrown-when-serialising-circular-dependent-iserializab)

Comment: @Sinatr Thanks for your comment and yes: Using `ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize` AND `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects` does the trick. But is there a manual solution without inflating JSON? Somewhat like a custom instance creator depending on the position of the JSON.NET reading stream...

Comment: In the future please avoid changing the question too much after you've got any response (especially answers). Simply ask a new question. The meta-data in json is [required](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm) for deserialization whenever it's a reference or type info. I don't know if you can avoid to have it easily. I am sure you don't want to write own deserializer and having `$id` and `$ref` is a little *pay* for what you get. You will need anyway some kind of identification to fill `Parent` property with corresponding reference. I doubt you can shorten it

Comment: Rather than a pure deserialization problem, you might think of this as an API design issue: how to ensure the parent/child relationships stay consistent?  Looked at it from that perspective. [Adding the Parent id to Serialization as Object class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37209142/3744182) might apply.